# Object doesn't support property or method 'colorbox'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, colorbox

I have an asp.net mvc page that allows a user to add Items to a list. The items are anchor elements that when click on, open up a pop box displaying detailed information about the item. Here is an example of an Item:

```
 <!-- <a class="SchoolDetails" href="/CollegeList/InstitutionDetailsPopup/6460?questionnaireId=1322">
Gettysburg College
</a> -->
```

After adding an item to the dom model, the following call is made

```
$('a.SchoolDetails').colorbox({
          overlayClose: false,
          iframe: false,
          overlayClose: true,
          width: 770,
          height: 530,
          close: "Close",
          onOpen: function () {
                  $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
                },
          onComplete: function () {
                         $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').hide();
                         Initialize();
                                $('#cboxLoadedContent').css('overflow', 'hidden').css('height', '100%');
                            }
                         });
```

The first item added to the page works as expected but subsequent calls fail with an Object doesn't support property or method 'colorbox' exception. The element does contain the cboxElement class attribute.  But when the user clicks on the link, the colorbox height and width are not set according to the parameters passed into the `$('a.SchoolDetails').colorbox()` call. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are not loading more than one jquery file. It seems that you are loading more than one Jquery file which is causing the problem. Any way just write "$.no conflict()" before calling "colorbox()" method.

Comment: Thank you. It turned out that the page displayed in the popup was reloading the JQuery and JQueryUI files.  Once I removed the <Script src=""> elements loading the files in the pop up page, the problem disappeared.